# Mapreduced: Hadoop under eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying setting up hadoop and eclipse

I did this following steps:

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment

but when I did this command

$ mvn install -DskipTests
$ mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true

I get this message:
command not found

I downloaded Maven but it didn't work

Any help please?

thanks

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Install Homebrew if you haven't already:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then:

```
brew install maven
```

You will then be able to use Maven.

Comment: You said that you had downloaded Maven, not installed it. Clearly Maven isn't installed if it's not found when you try to run it. These are the correct instructions for installing Maven on your OS, so you should undo what you've done and reinstall it as per the above instructions.